# How to prevent content from appearing outside the borders of a div?

Tags: css, hover, slide

I have this code but it does not work the way I want it to.

My intention was to create a box with a picture. When someone places their mouse curser over the box, the picture is supposed to be replaced by some informational text that slide up and and covers the picture to give you details about that picture.
But what I ended up was with this situation where the informational text appears **below** the picture and slides up to cover the picture when you hover over it.

```css
* {
  /*padding: 0;
  margin: 0;*/
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.main{
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
}

.main, .front, .back {
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  display: block;
}

.back{    
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  text-align: justify;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #333333;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.div-text {
  height: 220px;
}

.main:hover .back {
    display: block;
    top: -300px;
}

button {
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 0.35em 1.2em;
        border-radius: 0.5em;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        margin:3px;
        text-decoration: none;
        background-color: #fff;
        border: solid #32dc32;
        color: #33cc66;
        transition: all 0.2s;
    }

     button:hover {
                color: #fff;
                background-color: #33cc66;
    }
```

```html
<div class="main"> 
  
  <div class="front">
    <img src="https://www.gardeningknowhow.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/lawn-pH.jpg" alt="Avatar" style="width:100%;height:100%;">
  </div>
  
  <div class="back">
    
    <div class="div-text">
      <h1>Image Name</h1>
      <p>Image description blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah  </p>
    </div>
    
    <button>Read more</button>
  
  </div>
        
</div>
```

The content in the "back" div is not supposed to appear until **after** you hover over the "main" div and is definitely not supposed to appear **outside** the box. But for some reason it appears below it before I hover.

What should I do so that the contents do not appear outside the "main" div.

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution is to include the `.back` `div` in `.front` one, below the image.

They will still be visible and positioned one below the other. That's why you should use `overflow: hidden` on `.front`, so it will not show content that's outside its boundaries.

Note: If the `.back` container is not within `.front` one, `overflow: hidden` will not work.

Please check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/f7mopj3r/

Comment: Thanks. It worked for me but I did not need do all the changes you mentioned. I only include "overflow: hidden" in the ".front" class and it worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is influenced by https://stackoverflow.com/users/13146968/cristian-sarghe but I simplified it.

All you have to do is add the text "overflow:hidden;" within the "front" class and it works.

Below is the modified version of the code in the question that fixes the problem:

```css
* {
  /*padding: 0;
  margin: 0;*/
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.main{
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.main, .front, .back {
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  display: block;
}

.back{    
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  text-align: justify;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #333333;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.div-text {
  height: 220px;
}

.main:hover .back {
    display: block;
    top: -300px;
}

button {
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 0.35em 1.2em;
        border-radius: 0.5em;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        margin:3px;
        text-decoration: none;
        background-color: #fff;
        border: solid #32dc32;
        color: #33cc66;
        transition: all 0.2s;
    }

     button:hover {
                color: #fff;
                background-color: #33cc66;
    }
```

```html
<div class="main"> 
  
  <div class="front">
    <img src="https://www.gardeningknowhow.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/lawn-pH.jpg" alt="Avatar" style="width:100%;height:100%;">
  </div>
  
  <div class="back">
    
    <div class="div-text">
      <h1>Image Name</h1>
      <p>Image description blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah  </p>
    </div>
    
    <button>Read more</button>
  
  </div>
        
</div>
```

Thanks Cristian.